# Setting javascript defineGetter and defineSetter in a loop

Tags: javascript

Why does each iteration of this:

```
var o = {};

var foo = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5]];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  o.__defineGetter__(foo[i][0], function() {
    return foo[i][1]; 
  });
  console.info(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

Reset all previous assignments and output this:

```
{"a":1}
{"a":2,"b":2}
{"a":3,"b":3,"c":3}
{"a":4,"b":4,"c":4,"d":4}
{"a":5,"b":5,"c":5,"d":5,"e":5}
```

When what I expect / want to finish with is:

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4","e":"5"}
```

How do I achieve what I want?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function that returns a function that does what you want (this is just because of how closures work in JavaScript).  This example should work.

```
var o = {};

var foo = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3],['d',4],['e',5]];

var getFunc = function(val){
    return function() {
        return val; 
    }
};

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  var func = getFunc(foo[i][1]);
  o.__defineGetter__(foo[i][0], func);
}
console.info(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify this to my getter needs but the code in the OP was a heavily reduced case and I need more specific help. 

What should I do? ie, Should I ask another question or edit this one?

Comment: This question is already answered.  I guess asking another question is ok.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way that closures work. Variables are scoped to the functions they are defined in. There is no such thing as a loop variable (unless you are using a version of JS that has the `let` keyword). As a result, at the end of the loop, the value of `i` is the same in all of the anonymous functions you defined. You can see this by outputting `i` at the end of the loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  o.__defineGetter__(foo[i][0], function() {
    return foo[i][1]; 
  });
  console.info(JSON.stringify(o));
}
console.info(i); //outputs 5
```

EDIT: As pointed out, this is the same problem, as in this question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)